# Output Database records at data insertion automatically

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering if there was a type of code where when data is inputted into the database, a text file would be updated automatically. I have a website with food menu items and want to output food items to a text file, drinks to another text file and dessert items to another text file. Is it possible ?

```
SELECT tblnum,food_name FROM clients
enter code hereINTO OUTFILE '/tmp/food_orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use RethinkDB to achieve this.
https://www.rethinkdb.com/

With RethinkDB you can push to a script that processes the given json.

Comment: Thanks but was just thinking about a simple code that can update this file automatically at data insertion. Will have a look into this software thanks !